# Why mongodb refuses ssl connections?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, firewall

I am running a mongodb 3.2 instance on a vServer behind a firewall (which I am not allowed to configure). Mongo is reachable (and connectable) from anywhere (bind_ip: 0.0.0.0) if ssl is turned off in /etc/mongod.conf

Further I generated a CA, a server.pem and a client.pem (to connect via mongo-shell). These Certs are working fine, since I can connect to mongod from the machine mongod is running on:

```
$ mongo --host localhost --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem --sslCAFile ca.crt
```

BUT: when I try to connect from another machine with the same Certs it won't connect:

```
$ mongo --host mongo1.mydomain.net --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem --sslCAFile ca.crt

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: <ip>:27017/test
2016-08-22T22:29:17.632+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to <ip>:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2016-08-22T22:29:17.633+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server <ip>:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
@(connect):1:6
```

This is strange because the /var/log/mongodb/mongd.log says that mongod is listining on port 27017 for ssl connections (netstat says the same):

```
2016-08-22T21:09:10.182+0200 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2016-08-22T21:09:10.182+0200 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-08-22T21:09:10.183+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017 ssl
```

The ssl connection attempt from the other machine is not listed in the log file which is even more strange.

So I asked tcpdump:

```
23:10:32.984067 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 51, id 64132, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    <other_machine>.39644 > 172.12.51.23.27017: Flags [S], cksum 0xd3d0 (correct), seq 1809185188, win 29200, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 7275296 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:10:32.984112 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    172.12.51.23.27017 > <other_machine>.39644: Flags [S.], cksum 0x9506 (incorrect -> 0x14cf), seq 2653469724, ack 1809185189, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 93151206 ecr 7275296,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:10:33.041545 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 51, id 64133, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    <other_machine>.39644 > 172.12.51.23.27017: Flags [.], cksum 0xb3c5 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 7275313 ecr 93151206], length 0
23:10:33.047713 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 49309, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    <other_machine>.39644 > 172.12.51.23.27017: Flags [R.], cksum 0x55ec (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 229, length 0
```

The first reply from the mongo server has always an invalid checksum. But I really don't know if this is important or not. Actually I have no clue how to solve this an I am just hoping that anyone could help me with a hint.

cheers,
dymat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mehmet!

This was my first idea, too. But after talking to the sysadmin it turned out, that they had installed a application firewall, which classified SSL requests on port 27017 as *not* belonging to the mongodb server. The firewall expected unencrypted traffic on port 27017.

Once they reconfigured the firewall everything works as it is supposed to.

Bye,
dymat

Answer (score 0):

The hostname in the certificate might be different than the one used in mongo command. Try adding --sslAllowInvalidHostnames param at the end of mongo command.

```
mongo --host mongo1.mydomain.net --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem --sslCAFile ca.crt --sslAllowInvalidHostnames
```

See the mongodb connections options at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#cmdoption--sslAllowInvalidHostnames

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.